# update_usermeta don't work

Tags: functions, user-meta, fatal-error

When I return in the function $setfound, I become a white screen and when I return $setlink, it works fine.

```
function editsteamlink(){
$setlink = $_POST['steamlink']."/?xml=1";
$setresponse = wp_remote_get($setlink);
$setbody    = wp_remote_retrieve_body($setresponse);
$setxml = simplexml_load_string($setbody);
$setfound = $setxml->steamID64;
return $setfound;
}


function be_save_custom_avatar_field( $user_id ) {

    if ( !current_user_can( 'edit_user', $user_id ) ) { return false; }

        update_usermeta( $user_id, 'steamid64',editsteamlink());
        update_usermeta( $user_id, 'steamlink', $_POST['steamlink'] );

}
```

Answer (score 0):

You should enable [WP_DEBUG](http://codex.wordpress.org/Debugging_in_WordPress) mode, so that the white screen of death will give you a more useful error message.

The white screen could be caused by a typo, but it looks ok to me. Does your host have `simplexml_load_string()`? If you don't have the simple XML library, that could be why returning $setlink works, while returning $setfound causes WSOD.

I've re-written your code a bit so that it has `isset()` checks and so that you aren't relying on `$_POST` in your `editsteamlink()` function *and* it checks that the `simplexml_load_string` function exists.

```
function editsteamlink( $setlink = '' ){

    if( $setlink == '' || ! function_exists( 'simplexml_load_string' ) ){
        return '';
    }

    $setlink = untrailingslashit( $setlink ) ."/?xml=1";
    $setresponse = wp_remote_get($setlink);
    $setbody    = wp_remote_retrieve_body($setresponse);
    $setxml = simplexml_load_string($setbody);
    $setfound = (string)$setxml->steamID64;
    return $setfound;
}


function be_save_custom_avatar_field( $user_id ) {

    if ( !current_user_can( 'edit_user', $user_id ) ) { 
        return false; 
    }

    $steam_link = isset( $_POST['steamlink'] ) ? $_POST['steamlink'] : '';
    $steam_id = editsteamlink( $steam_link );

    update_usermeta( $user_id, 'steamlink', $steam_link );
    update_usermeta( $user_id, 'steamid64', $steam_id ); 

}
```

Untested, so your mileage may vary! :)

Comment: I habe found my mistakte thats the edit line                $setfound = (string)$setxml->steamID64;

Comment: Adjusted my answer to include that.